# Does order matter for these three .htaccess redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My goal is to accomplish the following:

1. Redirect the main domain into a subdirectory to clean up a cluttered server space
2. Not have the subdirectory name as part of the URL that shows in the browser address bar
3. Switch all http requests to https requests

It is my understanding correct that each of these needs its own set of rewrite rules. But, I wonder if they have to be in a particular order.

I have already cloned the site into the subdirectory.

Here are the rules I have:

```
# Aim main domain into subdirectory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} clientdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]

# Make all addresses https
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://clientdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

# Remove www from all addresses
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the order does matter most likely, though we cannot give a clear answer without you posting the actual rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect www and https before subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Make all addresses https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://clientdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove www from all addresses
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Aim main domain into subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} clientdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/ [L]
```

There was no redirection to the files in the subdirectory (only root with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` test) so I deleted the settings.